# IIS returns HTTP 500 response if user-agent is missing

Tags: iis-7, user-agent

I have a TXT file, stored in a subfolder on my web site, and our Windows application reads this file through HTTP.

Our application just sends a request with minimum headers: HTTP verb, filename, protocol on first line and Host key to point the server. Web server (which is a shared hosting) returns 500 to this request, where it returns 200 to request populated by browser.

Using Fiddler, I added User-Agent header info to request and voila, it returned 200. Regardless of what the value is.

Now, we'll add this user-agent info into our application, but it takes time to update all clients. Hosting staff say they did not make any changes on server settings.

Is there any solution that I can apply using web.config?

Regards,

Comment: Sure _sounds_ like a hosting issue, hard to create a workaround without first knowing the actual problem. Of course, buried in the [WebClient docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx), Microsoft says; "Also, servers may return 500 (Internal Server Error) if the user agent header is missing.", so one could say it's at least a documented failure mode.

Comment: Was this working previously? If yes, then your hosting provider made changes or your request is coming through a queried URL. If No, then in the same document that Joachim mentioned it also states " to retain queries in the response, you must add a user-agent header." something you may want to look into.